# Angular 11: My owl-date-time-calendar not consuming the click and close ng-popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, ngx-daterangepicker-material

Using owl-date-time-calendar inside the ng-popover menu

when use multiple ng-popover menu in one screen, and use `popover-trigger="'outsideClick'" & popover-trigger="focus"`

when selecting a date from owl-date-time-calendar inside ng-popover, the date picker does not consume the click, and ng-popover close automatically behaves like a click outside of the ng-popover and closing the ng-popover.

Angular : V11.0.4
Boostrap : V4.0.0

Answer (score 0):

The issue is still open on github.

You can follow the status of the issue here.

https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/3683